# AVAudiounit: I can't play a sound with an effect like delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, effects

I'm new to objective c and try to code a programm which can play a sound with an effect on it, like a reverb or delay. Unfortunately I'm only able to play the sound, but without the effect. I'm stuck for 3 days now and can't find a solution. Does anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong?
I tried this code, but with it there's no sound at all:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AVAudioEngine *engine = [AVAudioEngine new];
    AVAudioPlayerNode *playerA = [AVAudioPlayerNode new];

    playerA.volume = 0.5;


    NSURL *Mia1url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MIA1" ofType:@"m4a"]];

    AVAudioFile *MIA1 = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:Mia1url error:nil];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:MIA1.processingFormat frameCapacity:1024];
    [MIA1 readIntoBuffer:buffer error:nil];

    AVAudioUnitDelay *delay = [AVAudioUnitDelay new];
    delay.delayTime = 100;
    delay.wetDryMix = 90;

    [engine attachNode:playerA];
    [engine attachNode:delay];

    [engine connect: playerA to: delay format:MIA1.processingFormat];
    [engine connect: delay to: engine.mainMixerNode format: MIA1.processingFormat];

    [playerA scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];

    [engine prepare];
    [engine startAndReturnError:nil];

    [playerA play];
}
```

after that I tried this code but the sound is only coming without the effect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AVAudioEngine *engine = [AVAudioEngine new];
    AVAudioPlayerNode *playerA = [AVAudioPlayerNode new];

    playerA.volume = 0.5;

    NSURL *Mia1url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MIA1" ofType:@"m4a"]];

    AVAudioFile *MIA1 = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:Mia1url error:nil];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:MIA1.processingFormat frameCapacity:1024];
    [MIA1 readIntoBuffer:buffer error:nil];

    AVAudioUnitDelay *delay = [AVAudioUnitDelay new];
    delay.delayTime = 100;
    delay.wetDryMix = 90;

    [engine attachNode:playerA];
    [engine attachNode:delay];

    [engine connect: playerA to: delay format:MIA1.processingFormat];
    [engine connect: delay to: engine.mainMixerNode format: MIA1.processingFormat];

    [playerA scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];

    [engine prepare];
    [engine startAndReturnError:nil];

    //change
    self.playerA = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:Mia1url error:nil];

    //change from [playerA play] to:
    [self.playerA play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to instantiate your objects:

```
//AVAudioEngine *engine; // no instance exists. 
AVAudioEngine *engine = [AVAudioEngine new]; 
AVAudioPlayerNode *playerA = [AVAudioPlayerNode new];

...

AVAudioUnitDelay *delay = [AVAudioUnitDelay new];
...
```

Also, you have to initialize `playerA` only once and before using it.

For digging deeper you might want to checkout [Apples code samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: It's still not working :( But thank you for your help!

Comment: You are probably still initializing `self.playerA` _after_ you are (trying to) attaching it to the engine. 1st check out the linked sample code. 2nd update your question with your new findings and a proper description of what is happening "not working".

Comment: I updated my code. Unfortunately I can't find anything helpful in the code samples. Do you have any hint in which sample I can find the solution?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean "can not find helpful code sample". Click on the given link, click "download sample code" and you get a fully working Xcode project that does exactly what you are trying to do (play audio with effects). Take your time.